# Snowflake. Massive Updating of Rows / MicroPartitions handling

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When you execute a massive update ( b.e. a merge operation ), if in the same merge operation several rows of the same micro partition are updated, I guess Snowflake in background will "group" all these updates of this micro partition, and will generate only one new micropartition file from the original, instead of as many as row updated ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting... why do you think this?

Comment: Snowflake reads all of the micropartitions that contain data that needs to be updated, modifies the data that needs to be modified, and then generates new micropartitions in the same manner it would if you were inserting the data for the first time.  The creation of new micropartitions in this manner is very efficient with multiple threads executing the micropartition creation based on the size of the warehouse being used.  Not really sure I understand what your question is here?  Why would you want a micropartition for every row that was updated?